# Fail to use boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given such a data frame:

```
dt       val
02-09     0.1
02-09     0.2
02-09     0.15
02-10     0.3
02-10     -0.1
...
```

I want to use the boxplot to show the medium, variance of `val` in each `dt`:

```
 ggplot(data = df,aes(y=val,x=dt)) + geom_boxplot()
```

But what i got is :
[image]

It can observed that there is just one box. When I tried `outlier.colour = "red"`, all the points are red. Why? All the values are in the interval of (-1,1)

Comment: I see a box for each category. It's hard to see, but apparently you have many identical values (such as 0)?

Comment: @Roland really? But why are they so flat?

Comment: @Roland And they are apparent not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should explain the problem:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(10)
x <- c(x, rep(0, 100)) #add 100 zero values
boxplot(x)
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
#25% 50% 75% 
#  0   0   0
```

If you have many (almost) identical values, the quartiles are (almost) identical.

Comment: Solved. I will accept your answer in 3 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it still regards some of my points as outliers. Do you know how to coverage all the points in the box? Thanks.

Comment: You need to have a look at how a boxplot is defined again. The box covers the quartiles and can't cover all your points.

Comment: Sorry , I mean the line of the box, which points to the maximum and minimum value.